# Why are Patience Kys and Kara Swole alive?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I might be totally wrong, but:

Doesn't Kara Swole die in the last book of Ravenor?

Doesn't the same happen to Kys?

If the above are true, how are they alive again in Pariah?

Comment: I didn't think they died.  At least, not both of them.  One was definitely mentioned as being questioned by the inquisition in the epilogue of Ravenor, and i'm pretty sure the other deliberately left Ravenor's service after all the shit went down.  I don't have my copy with me, it's back home sadly.

Comment: KAra went over to the heretic ship on the last book. she got caught and interogated as i remember. they killed her? that is the part that im fussy about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning to those reading, this answer is almost entirely a spoiler of the last book of the Ravenor trilogy, as far as the characters Kara, Kys and Ravanor are concerned.

Both characters survive the events of the last book and are discussed in the epilogue.

kara is awaiting trial.

> Kara, my dear Kara, remains under arrest. They are keeping her here,
>   somewhere. Her hearing will follow mine and I hope by the Emporer's
>   grace I will be there to testify for her. She doesn't deserve this.
>
> *- Page 888, Ravenor, the Omnibus, by Dan Abnett*

Kys is in hiding, awaiting the outcome of Ravenor's trial:

> And Kys. Kys haunts the dining houses of the hive, loitering quietly,
>   waiting for me to be exonerated. I have no idea what she will do if
>   the Inquisition demands my incarceration or death. I wish she would
>   come and see me.
>
> *- Page 888, Ravenor, the Omnibus, by Dan Abnett*

Comment: hmmm... tought for sure she was dead after beeing captured!!!